# INSERT SELECT slower than SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, insert

I'm having a big problem with a simple part of a function with have a select that returns something like 350 records, the result I insert into a variable table to use later, but it is taken too long to execute.

If I execute just the select, without the insert, it takes 2 seconds to execute.

```
DECLARE @CHEQUES2 TABLE (CardCode VARCHAR(20),
                         Qtde Int,
                         Total DECIMAL(16,2),
                         Terceiro BIT,
                         PRIMARY KEY (CardCode, Terceiro))

INSERT INTO @CHEQUES2 (CardCode, Qtde, Total, Terceiro)
SELECT CARDCODE, COUNT(Numero) Qtde, sum(VALOR) Total, EmTerceiro
  FROM [VW_CP_teste] CHEQUES
 WHERE STATUS = 0
 GROUP BY CARDCODE, EmTerceiro
```

it is taken more than 30 minutes to execute, but the select alone takes only 2 seconds

Any idea of what is going on?

I tried using a cte, subselect, cursor, removing the primary key from variable table, nothing solved.

Edit: SQL Server 2012, 96gb RAM, 2 Sockets Xeon 2630

Edit2: Testing I got that if I use temp tables or real tables, it executes in 3 seconds.

Edit3: All I'm doing its a quite simple. This query is used inside a function, the reason to be a function its because it is used to join with tables/views and its used in a lot of other queries, like in Crystal Reports, so change it to a stored procedure will be a problem.

The function isn't new, the problem begins after I did some needed changes at the VW_CP_TESTE, with some more joins. I know the problem begins here, but the whole search of the VIEW do not got any struggling, just this part that uses it with variable tables. It is used with variable tables to gain performance, "saving" some resources before using it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012, 96gb RAM, 2 Sockets  Xeon 2630

Comment: For each case, generate the execution plans (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15) and then share them here by using this website: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: NB: Thats a table variable, not a temp table. But as @MatBailie says - the first point of call is looking at the execution plan to see what the hold up is!

Comment: That is the execution plan for the select, the select insert its running for 20 minutes and didnt finish... https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1oxUXat_  it takes 2 seconds to execute

Comment: i had to stop it, its running for more than 30 minutes. I'm testing, and if i use a Real table or a Temp table instead of variable table, it takes 3 seconds...

Comment: One difference with using a table variable is that it blocks parallelism. Difficult to see how that would explain a 180x speed up  though. What does the estimated execution plan for the table variable insert look like?

Comment: estimated execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By2F0maFd   the server has 12 cores, 24 threads, its 2 sockets of xeon 2630

Comment: @MartinSmith That is probably explained by a completely different serial plan, for whatever reason the compiler has chosen a poor join order for the serial plan. The plans is so complex, and with poor indexing, it's not surprising it's struggling

Comment: I would say even the parallel plan is poor, there are a number of good indexing opportunites. We need to see the full definition of `VW_CP_teste`

Comment: VW_CP_TESTE is realy big.... i saw the indexing opportunites, but the view its running well everywhere, the only place that is struggling its in this insert select. The problem is that is into a procedure, i think its not a good idea to use a Temp Table instead of a Variable Table, because of multiple calls

Comment: @Charlieface - I actually haven't really had time to compare the plans but even if they were identically shaped one other advantage the parallel plan has (apart form the 24 threads) is also the bitmap filtering https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/07/bitmap-magic.html

Comment: @Lucas - what issue do you see with multiple calls? Each call gets its own temp table and potentially they can be cached to avoid metadata contention. Table variables are themselves just a type of temp table with limitations.

Comment: Sorry, i said its a procudure, but it is a Function, as i know i cant create Temp Tables in a Function...

Comment: If it's inside a function, have you considered using a CTE rather than a table variable?

Comment: Even using a cte, the final result of the function its a table variable, when i join with the cte to insert into the variable table, the struggling happens

Comment: @Lucas - If you want people to see your replies, you have to tag their name in the comments that you make; we're ***only*** notified about comments that don't mention our names when the comments are on our own questions/answers.  I only saw this because my infrequently used living room PC's browser just happened to be on this page.

Comment: @Lucas - I think it's time you included actual code for a ***function*** that replicates your problem.  I recommend using mockup tables/data, so that we can replicate those, and so that you can cut out irrelevant logic from the function, focussing solely on the steps necessary for you to reproduce your problem.  It maybe, for example, that your function can be recoded as what's known as an Inline Table Valued Function *(using CTEs rather than table variables)* rather than a Multi-Statement Table Valued Function.  *(And also have the benefit of being inerrently faster.)*

Answer (score 0):

Although everything you are doing seems quite simple, try pre-selecting into a sql-server temp table via #tempTableName.  These "#" temp tables are valid only for the current session/connection and go away when the connection is done.  If you are using it in a stored procedure, then you will be able to query it directly from that.  If you still need your "declare" table instance, then do an insert into AFTER the #temp... something like

```
SELECT CARDCODE, COUNT(Numero) Qtde, sum(VALOR) Total, EmTerceiro
  into #myTempTable
  FROM [VW_CP_teste] CHEQUES
 WHERE STATUS = 0
 GROUP BY CARDCODE, EmTerceiro


DECLARE @CHEQUES2 TABLE (CardCode VARCHAR(20),
                         Qtde Int,
                         Total DECIMAL(16,2),
                         Terceiro BIT,
                         PRIMARY KEY (CardCode, Terceiro))

INSERT INTO @CHEQUES2 (CardCode, Qtde, Total, Terceiro)
   select CardCode, Qtde, Total, EmTerciro from #myTempTable
```

Maybe it is choking somewhere doing the aggregates before the insert into, so pulling to its own #temp will resolve that.  If timing still an issue, let me know.

**ALTERNATE OPTION**

Additionally, if your function is returning some sort of temp table result as you are preparing, a stored procedure can also do that.  I have many stored procedures in an app that I pass in a few parameters to apply against a query and the stored procedure does a bunch of pre-queries into #temp tables, parses, sorts, does other cleanup crud.  At the very end, I just do a

```
select * from #myResultCrud
```

and get the entire set returned back.  Just an option you may not have considered.

Comment: Thx for the answer DRapp, but it is a Function so i cant use a Temp Table. "Cannot access temporary tables from within a function."

Comment: @Lucas, could you "wrap" it by having a stored procedure run the SQL query into a #temp.  Call that before your declare cheques2, then insert?  Don't know if side-stepping where the temp table is used (via sub-call to the function) MIGHT bypass it?  Maybe editing your original post with a more complete post of your entire function might trigger something else?  Where are you using this result cheques2 table

Comment: @Lucas, see my revised answer / alternative option.

Comment: As you said DRapp, all i'm doing its a quite simple. The reason to be a function its because it is used to join with tables/views and its used in a lot of other querys, like in Crystal Reports, so change it to a Store Procedure will be a problem. The Function isn't new, the problem beggins after i did some needed changes at the VW_CP_TESTE, with some more joins. I Know the problem beggins here, but the whole search of the VIEW do not got any struggling, just this part that uses it with Variable Tables. It is used with variable tables to gain performance, "saving" some resoursers before using.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a similar problem I faced and asked 2 days back.

Please check this post -
[INSERT operation taking time for Table variable even for 0 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683400/insert-operation-taking-time-for-table-variable-even-for-0-rows)

It worked for me by using a temp table instead of table variable, but I understand you can not use a temp table here.

Try with the other workaround I mentioned in the post, i.e, changing database compatibility level. Also, can you tell what is database compability level for your database.
You can check with the query -

```
SELECT COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{database name}';
```

and update with this query -

```
ALTER DATABASE {database name} SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;
```

In my experience, table variable seems to perform really bad for the compatibility_level <= 100

Comment: Thanks for the answer Amit11794, all my databases are set to COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 110. As i was doing some research, for sql server 2012 110 is the max compatibility.